# Does $gcd(p,q)$ a period in string, where $p$ and $q$ are periods?

Tags: automata, combinatorics-on-words

Consider the string $s = a_{1}..a_{n}$.

Let's say that $p$ is a *period* when $a_{i} = a_{i + p}$ for all $i \in [1..n-p]$

Suppose there are two periods : $q$ and $p$, such that $q + p \le n$ then 
$\gcd(p,q)$ is also a period.

I tried to represent it : $\gcd(p,q) = \gcd(p,p+q)$ , but it doesn't help me.
Give any hint, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you mention is due to Fine and Wilf [1]. As indicated on the Wikipedia page [Théorème de périodicité de Fine et Wilf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_p%C3%A9riodicit%C3%A9_de_Fine_et_Wilf) (which unfortunately does not seem to exist in English), the theorem of Fine and Wilf can be stated in (at least) three different ways. Version $1$ is a slightly stronger version of your question. Version 3 is the original statement of [1].

**Version 1**. Suppose that $s$ has two periods $p$ and $q$. If $p+q-\operatorname{gcd}(p,q) \leqslant |s|$, then $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)$ is a period of $s$.

**Version 2**. Let $u$ and $v$ be two words, and suppose that for some positive integers $h$ and $k$, $u^h$ and $v^k$ have a common prefix of length $\geqslant |u|+|v|-\operatorname{gcd}(|u|,|v|)$. Then $u$ and $v$ are powers of a word of length $\operatorname{gcd}(|u|,|v|)$.

**Version 3**. Let $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ and $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ be two periodic sequences, of period $p$ and $q$, respectively. If $a_n=b_n$ for $p+q-\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)$ consecutive integers, then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

A proof of Version 2 is given in [[2, Prop.1.3.5, page 10]](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eberstel/Lothaire/lo1.ps). If you just want a hint, first try the case where $d = \operatorname{gcd}(|u|,|v|) = 1$, and then argue on the alphabet $A^d$ for the general case.

[1] N. J. Fine and H. S. Wilf, [Uniqueness theorems for periodic functions](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-01/S0002-9939-1965-0174934-9/home.html), Proc. of the AMS **16**, (1965), 109-114 (ISSN 0002-9939, DOI 10.1090/s0002-9939-1965-0174934-9).

[2] M. Lothaire, Combinatorics on words, Addison-Wesley Publishing Co., Reading, Mass., coll. Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications 17,‎ (1983) (ISBN 978-0-201-13516-9), Revised version Cambridge University Press, (1997), ISBN 978-0521599245